# How could I combine these 3 T-SQL statements into one?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have 3 queries that I want to combine. 1 query is for total sales, 1 is for canceled orders, and 1 is for orders that don't include specific product types. Just need the total sales $$ to output in a table format as they are now. The only thing that changes between the 3 is the where statement. Thanks!

Edit: I realize I said "Just need the total sales $$" ... what I meant was I just need the sales $$ for each query in one table. So $x, $y, $z ... x is the total sales, y is the sales dollars that got cancelled, and z is the sales dollars for the specific items.

```
SELECT Sum((Items.Total+Items.Shipping)*OrderDetails.Quantity) AS Total
FROM Promo INNER JOIN (Orders INNER JOIN (Items INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Items.ItemCode = OrderDetails.ItemCode) ON Orders.OrderNumber = OrderDetails.OrderNumber) ON Promo.Promo = Orders.Promo
WHERE ((Promo.OfferType)='Sale') AND ((Items.Date) Between '6/1/2010' And '12/31/2011');

SELECT Sum((Items.Total+Items.Shipping)*OrderDetails.Quantity) AS Canceled
FROM Promo INNER JOIN (Orders INNER JOIN (Items INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Items.ItemCode = OrderDetails.ItemCode) ON Orders.OrderNumber = OrderDetails.OrderNumber) ON Promo.Promo = Orders.Promo
WHERE (((Promo.OfferType)='Sale') AND ((Items.Date) Between '6/1/2010' And '12/31/2011') AND ((Items.Status)="Canceled"));

SELECT Sum((Items.Total+Items.Shipping)*OrderDetails.Quantity) AS BadItems
FROM Promo INNER JOIN (Orders INNER JOIN (Items INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Items.ItemCode = OrderDetails.ItemCode) ON Orders.OrderNumber = OrderDetails.OrderNumber) ON Promo.Promo = Orders.Promo
WHERE (((Promo.OfferType)='Sale') AND ((Items.Date) Between '6/1/2010' And '12/31/2011') AND ((Items.ProductType)<>2) AND ((Items.ProductType)<>6));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updated to reflect question clarification:

```
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN Items.Status <> 'Canceled' AND Items.ProductType = 4 THEN (Items.Total+Items.Shipping)*OrderDetails.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Total ,
       Sum(CASE WHEN Items.Status = 'Canceled' AND Items.ProductType = 4 THEN (Items.Total+Items.Shipping)*OrderDetails.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Canceled,
       Sum(CASE WHEN Items.ProductType <> 4 THEN (Items.Total+Items.Shipping)*OrderDetails.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS BadItems,
FROM Promo INNER JOIN (Orders INNER JOIN (Items INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Items.ItemCode = OrderDetails.ItemCode) ON Orders.OrderNumber = OrderDetails.OrderNumber) ON Promo.Promo = Orders.Promo
WHERE ((Promo.OfferType)='Sale') AND ((Items.Date) Between '9/1/2010' And '12/31/2010');
```

Comment: Made an edit, I was unclear in what I wanted. I want all 3 values in one table... thus need the 3 queries combined to provide all 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results on 1 row:

```
SELECT Total, Canceled, BadItems
FROM Query1, Query2, Query3
```

And if you want the results in 1 column, use a [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

```
Query1
UNION
Query2
UNION
Query3
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use a procedure which will accept three values as input which will suite your were statements and it will give results in one table as want. if you are stuck let me know , i will help.